# npm install express --save command gives 403 forbidden error even after setting proxy

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have done the following steps before installing the module `express`.

However I am getting a `403 error`.

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm config set proxy  http://user:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@host:port
```

> ERROR
>   npm ERR! code E403
>   npm ERR! 403 Forbidden: express@latest

Comment: what command do you use in installing the express? What error message do you get when you run the npm install?

Comment: Thank you so much for the format edit @alexi2 . Its my first question here . Totally new to "Asking question" .

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved . The problem was with the proxy address itself. my company uses a pac file . Network team had given me one proxy address to try.But it was not helping. I downloaded the pac. and tried with a new proxy address . And the 403 forbidden issue was resolved as proper authorization was done.