# I am getting 403 error while running npm login command?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install

Getting error after running npm login command.
I have set no_proxy, proxy and registry. But when i am hitting npm login command its asking for username and password and email and after entering its throwing 403 error.

```
npm ERR! E403
npm ERR!registry returned 403
```

In log file error is :
http 403 <- Forbidden  http://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/login/

Comment: did you set your proxy over https?

Comment: yes. i set already proxy over http not https.

Comment: Your error means this package is more or less broken. and see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47526109/13126651